# Specifying Google perftools to g++ for using C++ in R

Tags: c++, r, profiling, rcpp

I installed Google perftools (google-perftools 1.7-1ubuntu1), and add -lprofiler to PKG_LIBS in R, when compiling the C++ code.

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(Rcpp)

Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-fopenmp")
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-fopenmp -lprofiler")

sourceCpp('my.cpp')
```

The output is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprofiler
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sourceCpp_17496.so] Error 1
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG    -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c my.cpp -o my.o g++ -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_17496.so my.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -fopenmp -fopenmp -lprofiler -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR 
Error in sourceCpp("my.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

WARNING: The tools required to build C++ code for R were not found.

Please install GNU development tools including a C++ compiler.
```

Even if I run g++ in bash, I get the same error

```
$ g++ -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o sourceCpp_17496.so my.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -fopenmp -fopenmp -lprofiler -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprofiler
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I wonder why `-lprofiler` doesn't specify google perfotools? How can I solve the problem? Thanks!

My g++ is g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick ones:

1. Do you actually have the package libgoogle-perftools-dev installed?  Ie do you have shared and static libraries `/usr/lib/libprofiler.*` ?  This is the mother of all development FAQs: you need package `libfoo` to *run* code against foo, and package `libfoo-dev` to *compile* against foo.
2. I have old working examples in the slides from my 'HPC with R' [talks](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html) from a few years ago; those should all work as is.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks! I have some further question of using google perftools to profile my R program using Rcpp. I can't post a new question now, because of limitation of 6 posts per 24 hours. So can I ask you here?

Comment: Here is what I did. (1) First, in my R script 'my.R', I have `Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-fopenmp -lprofiler")` (intended for `sourceCpp()` to compile `my.cpp` with the profiler option), followed by `sourceCpp(my.cpp)`,  followed by calling to some functions defined in `my.cpp`. (2) Second, in shell, I ran the R script by `CPUPROFILE="myprof.log" R -f my.R`, which generated a log file `myprof.log`. (3)Finally, I examined the log file with ` google-pprof --text R myprof.log | less`, but `myprof.log`(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/R/myprof.log)) doesn't show anything meaningful. Wrong?