# Why do we need development version of libraries to compile against?

Tags: compilation

[Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23656177/156458) said

> This is the mother of all development FAQs: you need package libfoo to
>   run code against foo, and package libfoo-dev to compile against foo.

I wonder why?

What are different between libfoo-dev and libfoo?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you ask @Dirk in a comment to his answer?

Comment: Because I am scared of asking him further.

Comment: No worries. I don't bite.

Answer (score 2):

Examples, `man` files and header files.

Examine https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/zlib1g-dev/filelist and https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/zlib1g/filelist for an example.